# How can I use nested destructuring with objects with reused keys?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have a message from my websocket:

```
var message = {
  spell: {
    symbol: 'my-spell'
  },
  target: {
    symbol: 'my-target'
  }
};
```

I'm trying to learn destructuring, so I wrote the following code:

```
let {
  spell: {
    spell_symbol: symbol
  },
  target: {
    target_symbol: symbol = null
  }
} = message;
console.log('spell symbol: ' + spell_symbol);
console.log('target symbol: ' + target_symbol);
```

This gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: Identifier 'symbol' has already been declared
```

Have I written the syntax wrong, or can you not reuse keys like `symbol` in your nested object? How would I extract `target.symbol` from `message`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up the order of property name and target expression, it should be

```
const {
  spell: {
    symbol: spell_symbol
  },
  target: {
    symbol: target_symbol = null
  }
} = message;
console.log('spell symbol: ' + spell_symbol);
console.log('target symbol: ' + target_symbol);
```

Comment: @DavidBray See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40698920/1048572) or [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43903662/1048572) for an explanation